# Calculate $p$-adic metric

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Let $p$ be a prime. Define the $p$-adic modulus of $x$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ as $$ x= \frac{a}{b} \cdot p^{n}.$$ where $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and do not contain $p$ as a factor as $|x|_p=p^n$. For example, $\vert \frac{95}{63}\vert_{17} = 1$(*).

Define $d_p: \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ by 
$$d_p(x,y) = \vert x - y \vert_p.$$
$d_p$ is a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$. Calculate $d_5(1, 10^{431})$(**)

My **questions**: - How do you come up with (*) and how do I calculate (**)? I'm quite lost here.

Comment: and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very straight forward calculation based on the definition.

$||x||_p=p^k$ where $p^k$ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $x$. In the case of fractional $x$, we interpret powers of $p$ in the denominator as having negative exponents.

**First Problem:** $$\frac{95}{63}=\frac{5\cdot 19}{3^2\cdot 7}=\frac{5\cdot 19}{3^2\cdot 7}(17)^0$$ we introduce the term $17^0$ since there aren't any factors of $17$ in the fraction. By the definition, we see that the norm is now $17^0=1$

**Second Problem:** factoring $10^{431}-1$ is onerous, but in this case we don't have to! We know that the result is $4\pmod{5}$ and so just like in the first example the answer is $5^0=1$

Comment: Thanks, Stella Biderman. Could you clarify how we know that he result is 4 (mod 5)?

Comment: @Taufi 1$0^k-1$ is always $4\pmod{5}$ since it's one less than a multiple of $5$

Comment: Okay, I think I am almost there. Suppose now that it's not $d_5(10^{431}, 1)$ but instead $d_3(10^{431}, 1)$. The difference would yield a long line of 9's I guess. Those should be divisible by 3, but how do I proceed in this case then?

Comment: @Taufi You figure out what the largest power of $3$ deciding the difference is. The answer is $9$ because 3 doesn't divide 430

Comment: I'm sorry I have to prolong the question in this comment-type fashion but I cannot quite follow your reasoning. Suppose I have to calculate $\vert\vert 999....9 \vert\vert_{3}$. According to your previous comment that would be $3^9$ when I understood right. But why? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: The question is, what is the largest power of $3$ that divides $x$. That is the answer to $||x||_3$. In the case of $x=99\cdots 99$ it depends on how many $9$'s there are.

Comment: Well, what about in the case of $\vert \vert 10^{431} - 1\vert\vert$? There are 431 9's. I understand that I have to find the largest exponent of 3 that yields that number together with some fraction. But how do I derive that exponent together with the fraction properly or in a systematic manner?

Comment: $3$ divides a number iff it divides the sum of its digits. Once we divide by $9$, we are left with a string of $430$ $1$'s. $430$ is therefore the sum of the digits, which isn't divisible by $3$, so the original number is only divisible by $9$

Answer (score 0):

The definition you have cited is incomplete. It should say that if $x=\frac{a}{b}\cdot p^n$ where $a,b$ are integers not divisible by $p$ and $n$ is an integer, then $\lvert x\rvert_p=n$, and by convention, $\lvert 0\rvert_p=0$ Since $95$ and $63$ are both indivisible by $17$, you get (*) immediately.

This should make it easy to do the second part as well.